# Как анимировать по клику выезжание элемента LinearLayout и сдвиг остальных эелементов под ним?

Tags: java, android

Как я могу сделать что бы по клику у меня выезжал элемент LinearLayout и сдвигал остальные эелементы под ним?

Comment: ± изменяя `android:layout_marginLeft`

Answer (score 0):

Пока сделал так

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(orders.get(position).getHeight(), 1)
                        .setDuration(2000);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        /*width*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        /*height*/ holder.resycle_view_my_orders_anim.getHeight()
                );
                holder.resycle_view_my_anim.setLayoutParams(param);

                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        holder.resycle_view_my_anim.getLayoutParams().height = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        holder.resycle_view_my_anim.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
```